# Use of FireDAC's macrofunction LIMIT on subqueries

Tags: sql-server, oracle, delphi, firedac

I want to know if there are any restrictions on using FireDAC's "LIMIT" macrofunction on subqueries like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TABLE1 WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT TOP 1 FIELD1 FROM TABLE2 )
```

With LIMIT applied it would be as follows:

```
SELECT {LIMIT(0,10)} * FROM TABLE WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT {LIMIT(0,10)} FIELD1 FROM TABLE2 )
```

If so, I would like to know what alternatives exist to limit the number of rows returned in a subquery considering that it is necessary to be compatible with more than one database manager (Oracle and SQL Server).

This is a simplified use case, in a real scenario it is expected to use this macrofunction in much more complex queries.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't look like any are documented by EMBA.  Have you looked at [this](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/System_Macro_Functions_(FireDAC)) in the docs?  it says "The function can be put in any place of the SQL command." - the "of the" is a bit strange, and presumably should be read as "in the".

Comment: Generally the query inside an EXISTS() is optimized by the database with the knowledge the row(s)/data does not actually have to be returned.

Comment: {LIMIT} will be applied only to the top level SELECT. Not to any of subselects.